# IE11 - Throwing error in console , while it is working fine in chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

Below is my code snippet , where I am getting error like  , in IE11

**SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'init' of undefined or null reference**

**SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'**

But it is working fine in Chrome and other browser like Edge , 
kindly provide with some viable solution .

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(function () {
        color.shades.init({
            url: {},
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: `color.shades` is not set. Where are you setting that?

Comment: Pretty sure IE11 doesn't support trailing commas like that either

Comment: IE11 tolerates trailing commas well, maybe you're running the code in a downgraded document mode.

Comment: I made a test with the code snippet you providing. It shows `'color' is undefined` in Chrome and IE. Could you please provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a test and see how to help? With only the above code we can't locate the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Hi @Raj, answer your own question if you found a solution

Comment: @Raj, a tip: instead of editing the question to also contain your fix for the issue, it is common to post it as an Answer to your own Question. Even if you found it by yourself :-). That keeps the site clear: the question is on top, and the answer is in the Answers area.

Comment: @peter B  , thanks for suggestion , will follow the same . :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi all thanks for your answer , but I was able to trace the issue , as I was using Shorthand function like ,

```
 ToggleEquipmentVisibility() {
              Code...... ;
                },
```

which IE11 does not support , so changing it to call back function , like

```
ToggleEquipmentVisibility : function() {
          Code...... ;
            },
```

Solved my issue :) for both the errors .